# QEMU window doesn't display the first lines

Tags: macos, homebrew, qemu

I'm using QEMU for learning some very basic OS Development, yk just printing some text to the screen and so on.
I'm working on MacOS (M1 Mac Mini) and installed QEMU via Homebrew.

Now, when I run QEMU, the thing shown on the screenshots happen.

[image: QEMU when I run the simple halt program]

Here, QEMU just executes a simple program that does nothing for infinity. I know that it actually should print "SeaBIOS" and the version at the top line.

Well, I actually don't care about seeing this line, but the same thing happens when I run any program. For example, the window shown below should display a "Hello World!" message:
[image]

As you can see, the first line and a part of the second line are cut off. But when I go View > Enter Fullscreen, they're there. So somehow my window is too small or something like that. I changed nothing at any settings, everything is just default. I just wanted to ask if someone has idea what could be the problem here.

Reinstalling QEMU via homebrew reinstall didn't work.

If noone knows what's the problem here, is there a way to completely reinstall qemu or reset the settings? Are there any app data files or so I'd have to delete?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a bug in the Cocoa renderer of Qemu. You could try using VNC instead. I have a fix for the bug somewhere, I should tidy that up and submit it now that 8.2 has been released and new patches are being accepted for 9.0.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering that fast... And how can you change the renderer for QEMU? Do I have to put it into command line arguments or something?

Comment: To use VNC, pass `-display none -vnc :0` on the command line and connect your VNC client to localhost:5900. You may need to use a value other than 0 if your computer is already listening on that port. (the number passed to `-vnc` is an offset of 5900, so `:1` means 5901, etc.